# Prepare a change set to deploy an updated trigger from dev to Production

Tags: change-set

I am preparing a change set to deploy an updated trigger from sandbox to production. Now, there are associated classes and other dependencies. Do I have to add all the dependencies in the 'Add dependencies' section along with it ? This is my first time using a change set.

Answer (score 0):

No, a changeset isn't any different from any other deployment method in this regard.

If you have code that uses a particular custom field, that field will (or should) show up as a dependency. If that field is already in your target org, then there's no need to deploy it again.

It boils down to "if there is a change between pieces of metadata in 2 orgs, deploy the things that changed".

Comment: Thank you and does it also mean that I would not have to add helper classes as well since I have not added anything new in those classes. Am I correct ?

Comment: @user3920709 If it exists in your target org, and there are no differences in the metadata in the two orgs, then it doesn't need to be deployed. The feature name should give you a clue here. A _Change_ set is something you use to deploy _changes_.

Comment: Thank you. Perfect!